Problemas con un programa en PHP que se detiene, sera el programa o rabbitmq?
Tengo un contenedor docker que levanto con docker-compose utilizando un yaml, el cual al cargarse manda llamar una imagen personalizada donde se ejecuta unicamente PHP para con el objetivo de ejecutar un script en el mismo lenguaje (PHP), una vez levantado el contenedor y ejecutado el script, este funciona y hace sus tareas sin problema alguno, pero en cierto punto o momento, deja de hacer sus tareas.
El programa PHP al levantarse manda llamar un ciclo FOR infinito el cual tiene la tarea:

Inicia un ciclo for inifinto.
Llama una funcion que a hace la tarea de conectar a un FTP Seguro.
Extrae la data existente en una carpeta especifica del FTP Seguro.
Abre una conexion a RabbitMQ y guarda los datos en una cola.
Termina de guardar, sale de la funcion y se ejecuta un sleep de 10 segundos.
Se repite el proceso gracias al ciclo for infinito.

cat docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
   ms04:
     container_name: ftpreader
     image: miusername/my-php74:latest
     restart: always
     volumes:
       - /home/websites:/app:rw
       - /tmp:/tmp:rw
       - /home/websites/libs/04_ftp_reader.php:/app/src/libs/run.php:rw
     networks:
       - mired
networks:
  mired:

cat 04_ftp_reader.php


....
for( ;; ) {
    mifuncion();
    sleep(10);
}


function mifuncion() {
    $myDrive= '/mnt/data/new_files/';
    $ftp= new MyFTPClass();
    $ftp->conectarFtp();
    $data= $ftp->listFilesFTP(); // array de archivos 

    foreach( $data as $k ) {
        $bufData= $ftp->getFileByName($k); // extraigo los datos

        // mydrive=ruta, k=nombre_archivo, bufData=stream data
        $ftp->saveOnDrive($myDrive, $k, $bufData); // guardo los datos en un drive compartido

        if( !file_exists($myDrive.$k) ) {
            echo "\n[ERROR] Archivo no pudo guardarse en: ". $myDrive.$k;
        }
        else {
            echo "\n[OK] Archivo guardado en: ". $myDrive.$k;

            $cola= 'micola';
            $ra= new RabbitMQ(); // abro conexion a rabbitmq
            $data= json_encode(array(
                "filename"=>$k, // nombre del archivo
                "path"=>$myDrive, // directorio donde se guarda
                "full_url"=>$myDrive.$k, // ruta completa
                "status"=>1 // 1=activo, 0=inactivo (cuando ya se haya terminado de hacer algo)
            ));
            $ra->send($cola, $data); // mandamos guardar los datos json a la cola
            $ra->close();
        }
    }
}

Intentando resolverlo por mi cuenta, tras verificar que el programa por alguna razon ya no inyecta datos en la cola de rabbit, tengo que reiniciarlo :'(
Asi que indagando coloco esta info y espero sirva de algo:
docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS      NAMES
f2348c2dd6b6   miusername/my-php74:latest   "php /app/src/libs/r…"   2 weeks ago   Up 2      ms04

docker exec -it ms04 /bin/bash
ps aux
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root           1  0.2  1.7 105036 31640 ?        Ss   Sep04   6:38 php /app/src/libs/run.php
root           7  0.0  0.1   4248  3408 pts/0    Ss+  16:14   0:00 /bin/bash
root          21  0.3  0.1   4248  3460 pts/1    Ss   16:41   0:00 /bin/bash
root          34  0.0  0.1   5900  2852 pts/1    R+   16:41   0:00 ps aux

Hasta este punto, creo que el programa NO ESTA CAIDO o MUERTO, sino que esta como "dormido" o sera que la conexion a Rabbit de congelo o que podra ser?
Por donde mas podria indagar?

Prueba un enfoque diferente: en vez de un ciclo infinito configura un cron en tu contenedor para que ejecute la tarea cada xx tiempo (segun tu necesidad), haciendo control no exisa otra en ejecución (puedes aplicar un bloqueo a través de un fichero por ejemplo).

Al parecer la función saveOnDrive es la que hace la magia de guardar la información del FTP, si tienes oportunidad de verificar la conexión FTP si está viva o muerta.
La desventaja es que si tienen la seguridad alta, puede matar la conexión y no reportarlo directamente, ya sea en pantalla o en los logs; pero si es posible ver la conexión si tienes alguna forma de monitorearlo (por ejemplo por SSH)

Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.
